# disabling a checkbox permanently

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working on a gridview ..What I want is when a user checks a checkbox and select a record,the checkbox should become disable.Also when any other user selects the same row the checkbox should remain disabled to second user also...What will be the code for the same?

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild" runat="server"  AutoPostBack= "true" CommandArgument= '<%# Eval("id") %>'  />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the checkbox on which i want to apply what I asked .

Comment: Did u try anything ? share the code

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question in more details?

Comment: I just want to disable a checkbox permanently.That is one user checks a checkbox and the checkbox become disable. and remain in the same state forever (ie disabled forever)

Comment: Did you write any code for this so far? Any issue you are facing any error or exception with that code?

Comment: if you add a bit column in your database for this record, everytime you checked checkbox on changed event ,set column value true and put check on front end that if check is true than disable it.It will work for all users

Comment: **Also when any other user selects the same row the checkbox should remain disabled to second user** what do you mean by second user here.

Comment: It would be better if you can explain the business use case.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz  second user here refers to the mutiple users who are going to log in the same webpage where I am having this issue....

Comment: Is your problem solved or not?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz  No...Not yet...!!

Comment: @kritiupadhyay: You have to save the checked value in database, and on that value handle the checked/unchecked of checkbox.

Comment: OK.Can you send me code with an example

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
$("yourCheckBox").click(IsChecked);
function IsChecked() {
if (this.checked) {
$("yourCheckBox").attr("disabled", true);
}
}
```

If you want it disabled forever, you need some manipulation at your db end, add a column, lets say, `IsDisable` in your table from where you are fetching checkbox data and set its value within your grid. By deafult the value will be false and update that value on userclick within your table. That's it.

Comment: This is disabling the checkbox for one time only..Not permanently

Comment: @M Adeel Khalid  Can you please send me the proper code ...

Answer (score 1):

You could do a callback and disable the checkbox server side..